# How do to show only markered logs in slf4j?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, markers

I'm developing a subsystem of a big project. So I made a special logging marker to separate logs of that subsystem from the main project logs.

How do to show only markered logs by that special logging marker in slf4j?

Comment: An alternative could be to use special logger names for your sub-project, and then filter as described in the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it has to be done in the underlying logging framework. In Logback you could add a filter to your log appender. It's described in the doc: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html. Log4j seems to have a similar mechanism: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html, I havn't tried it, though.